# How to properly declare a recursive interface with optional properties of a mapped type

Tags: typescript, interface, option-type, recursive-datastructures, mapped-types

I am trying to implement an interface of the shape of

```
type someUnion = "foo" | "bar";

interface RecursiveInterface {
  a: number;
  b: Array<number>;
  [key in someUnion]?: RecursiveInterface;
}
```

to describe objects like

```
const someObject: RecursiveInterface = {
  a: 2,
  b: [1,5],
  foo: {
     a: 0,
     b: [2,6],
     bar: {
        a: 8,
        b: 7
     }
  }
}
```

However this leads to the error `A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.`

Suggesting that the following is viable

```
type mappedType = {
  [key in someUnion]?: RecursiveInterface;
}
```

which throws no errors, but as the initial error suggests, does not allow additional properties.

Extending the initial interface with the mappedType appears to work though, as in

```
interface RecursiveInterface extends mappedType {
    a: number;
    b: Array<number>
}
```

Now my question is, **is this the correct way to define the desired interface or is there a more concise option, that does not require extending the interface with an additional mapped type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your definition (except maybe that naming conventions generally use UpperPascalCase for new types, so `SomeUnion` instead of `someUnion` and `MappedType` instead of `mappedType`, and the type parameter in a mapped type is also a type, not a key name, so `K` instead of `k`, but these are just conventions, like coloring the decaf coffee pot orange; not *necessary*, but helpful to distinguish between different things).

Still, if you want something more concise you can use [the `Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [the `Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) utility types so that you can immediately extend a named type instead of having to create a new named type:

```
type SomeUnion = "foo" | "bar";

interface RecursiveInterface extends Partial<Record<SomeUnion, RecursiveInterface>> {
    a: number;
    b: Array<number>;
}
```

This works as desired:

```
const someObject: RecursiveInterface = {
    a: 2, b: [1, 5], foo: {
        a: 0, b: [2, 6], bar: {
            a: 8, b: 7 // error, number is not number[]
        }
    }
}
```

(at least I *think* that's what you want, since your example gives an invalid `b` property at a nested level ‍♂️)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgVQHYEs6qgXigIgDM458oAfAgIwEMAnfAbgChn1VgI7CaBjaAEoReAVzoBndADcIASQ5ce-KBAAenVABNxUAAr1g6GgBsAPEN5w6m0-CRpMqADRQLYyTPmdufCAD4-KABvZigwqBoALihUEQQqLhZwqCpogEE6OhoQU1j4rj8WAF9WZktUcWAocUQIAHkqACthYGi3CWk5BR9lPBDkqKgAJhdUqABtAEYXAFYAXRdiOGj+5PDBgAZR6PGRqAA2BZT6FdC188GADm2oAHYoAHoHlUyrFzyEuih0HVQ4Ko+XHGczO5xKyRKJWYQA)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `type` and intersect definitions instead:

```js
type RecursiveInterface = {
  a: number;
  b: Array<number>;
} & {
    [key in someUnion]?: RecursiveInterface;
}
```

It is more "grouped together", if it is what you are after